# Get Full Name of Directory with String It Contains

Tags: java, firefox

I'm trying to use Java to get the full name of a directory using a string it contains.  Basically, my use case is I want to be able to work with files in the Firefox default profile directory.  So my Firefox profile directory in Windows 7 has the following path:

```
C:\Users\myUser\AppData\Roaming\Mozilla\Firefox\Profiles\s529v6bj.default
```

And I'm wanting to work with the `prefs.js` file in that directory.  However, when porting my code to another machine, the string before the `.default` could be anything, and there could even be more characters after `default`.  The one thing I can guarantee is that there will be only one directory in `Profiles` containing the string "default".  I want the directory returned as a string, basically like ...

```
String ffProfileDir = System.getProperty("user.home")+"\\AppData\\Roaming\\Mozilla\\Firefox\\Profiles\\*.default*";
```

Except I know of course just throwing some asterisks on either side of the `.default` isn't gonna do the trick.  Any suggestions?

Comment: Can't you just point a File instance to that directory and then iterate through its children to find the file you're looking for?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work for what you want.

```
public class DirectoryReader {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        readDirectory();
    }

    public static void readDirectory() {
        String root = System.getProperty("user.home") + "\\AppData\\Roaming\\Mozilla\\Firefox\\Profiles\\";
        File file = traverseFolder(new File(root));
        String fileName = file.getName(); // if you want to get the directory name
    }

    public static File traverseFolder(File root) {
        if (root.isDirectory()) {
            File[] files = root.listFiles();
            if (root == null) {
                return null;
            }

            for (File f : files) {
                String fileName = f.getName();
                if (fileName.matches(".*default.*")) {
                    System.out.println(fileName);
                   return f;
               }
           }
        }

        return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: Wait, does the `".*default.*"` match the literal dot in `.default`?

Comment: Yes it would. It would match any string with 'default' in it. the regex characters ".*" means zero or more occurrence of any character.

Comment: Ah yeah I see I didn't specifically ask to match on the dot in my question anyways, and yeah of course the wildcard will match it regardless.  Point taken.  Thank you very much for your answer.